# Enable NTFS long paths does not allow copying files over the network

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-10

I have a Server 2016 file server and a Windows 10 client (fully patched) and even though I've enabled "NTFS long paths", I still get "the file names would be too long for the destination folder" error.

I can, however create files that are longer than 260 characters on the server. Is there another setting I need to modify in order to copy files with long path names?

Comment: What application are you using to copy the files?  It also has to be long-path aware.

Comment: Windows Explorer.

Comment: And that works on the server?  My understanding was that Windows Explorer doesn't support long paths at all, but my knowledge may be out of date.

Comment: I can create 280 char paths (including filename) on windows explorer so I'm assuming it does support it.

Comment: According to [this 2016 post](https://win32.io/posts/Long-Path-Support-In-Powershell) Explorer fakes long path support by "using the 8.3 shortname name for folders close to the root" so perhaps this is misleading you?  Not sure why it wouldn't work just as well from the client though.